# Bitshift error in Matlab 2016a

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

```
if strcmp(mappingtype,'u2') %Uniform 2
  newMax = samples*(samples-1) + 3; 
  for i = 0:2^samples-1
    j = bitset(bitshift(i,1,samples),1,bitget(i,samples));
```

While trying to run the program, i'm getting the following error in the function.

Error using bitshift
ASSUMEDTYPE must be an integer type name.

Comment: What is your purpose of using bitshift(i,1,samples)?

bitshift() usually takes 2 arguments. Do you want to compute i * 2 ^ samples with the bitshift()?

Comment: 3rd one is the assumed type... their its was given as samples...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I know that this is a old question, but I am posting here in case someone else has a similar question.
This is because Matlab has stopped supporting bitshift operation with three number arguments. so instead of using
`bitshift(i,1,samples)` use `bitand(bitshift(i,1),2^samples-1)`

reference- https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/1ttat5/help_me_with_bitshifting_and_bit_truncation/

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, just use two arguments for computing  i * 2 ^ samples by using bitshift(i, samples)

Or, use bitshift(1, samples) to get 2 ^ samples.

The third argument is for assuming data type and it should be like 'int16' or 'int8', not a variable for computing.

Comment: If i change bitshift to 2 arguments.. i'm getting dimensional error

Comment: Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Action3D_LBP (line 133)
F_train = F_train./(repmat(sqrt(sum(F_train.*F_train)), [Dim,1]));

Comment: Could you show me the sample itself? The matrix dimensional error should be a different error from bitshift one. When you have an error at bitshift, you just get an error message of bitshift only whereas there are other errors because bitshift is upper than any other errors. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is Octave code and not Matlab's. In Octave's bitshift operator, 3 arguments are allowed. I tried this, turns out that j's binary representation is the left rotation of i's binary representation.